# Statistics Youtube

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am "playing" with YouTube API,just knowing number of visits, ratings, favourites, etc. I would like to know if there is any option to obtain data youtube uses to draw the statistic graphs, such it is done in youtube page?

I mean knowing the number of video plays along the time.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Youtube 2.0 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight) you can mention the `user_starttime` and `user_endtime` and get a insight report that contains data to a period of up to 31 days beginning no earlier than March 1, 2009.

You can get samples for every month you want to plot.

---

Also there is a [Youtube Analytics program](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/) that is in beta

> - Metrics are individual measurements of user activity, such as video views or ratings (likes and dislikes).
> - Dimensions are common criteria that can be used to aggregate data, such as the date on which the user activity occurred or the country where the users were located. Dimensions can also be used to filter data. For example, you could retrieve data only from a specific country or for a specific video.

Comment: Hi! First of all thanks for your answers 
But my idea is to analyse a video upload by a third person, not mine or my activity. 
In fact I checked it here--> https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight 
And I found that you can use YouTube Insight options if:
    1)A video entry contains a link to Insight data if the authenticated user retrieving the entry owns the video.
    2)A profile entry contains a link to Insight data for the channel if the authenticated user is retrieving his or her own profile.
So, What I pretend is impossible, don't it?

Comment: Yes it appears so, if you are building a tool for someone you let them authenticate and view their own stats. You won't be able to see it though. Can you try using the Analytics program where you can have a `claimedStatus` = `claimed` and `uploaderType` = `thirdParty`

Answer (score 0):

I have found, and test, this code that allows me get likes and dislikes from youtube videos. Altough it doesn't allow me to get statistics graph (and I think it is impossible) I get more information from the videos :)

Reno thanks for your attention!!!

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/UBbiyE3Cw5M

by the way I tried to use  Analytics program with c#...no good results